# Validate JSON fields sort order

Tags: json, sorting, parsing, jq, jsonlines

I have the following JSON records stored in a container

```
{"memberId":123,"memberCity":"Chicago","lastTransaction":1504155600000}
{"memberId":123,"memberCity":"Chigago","lastTransaction":150175600000}
{"memberId":123,"memberCity":"New York","lastTransaction":150195600000}
```

I am looking to validate that the sort order in which these records are stored are sorted by memberId ASC, memberCity ASC, lastTransaction ASC

Is there a way via jq that I can assert (true/false) the sort order, taking multiple fields into account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any solution that requires using the -s command-line option has the drawback of requiring more memory than is needed. Similarly using `sort` is inadvisable in general, but if one wants a concise and simple solution, one could go with:

```
jq -s 'map([.memberId, .memberCity, .lastTransaction]) | . == sort'
```

or even in the specific case given:

```
jq -s 'map(.[]) | . == sort'
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a reasonably efficient solution, presented in a way that hopefully makes it easy to understand and adapt:

```
def sorted:
  if length <= 1 then true
  else map([.memberId, .memberCity, .lastTransaction])
  | .[0] <= .[1]
  end;

def pairs(stream):
  foreach stream as $i ([]; 
    .[-1:] + [$i]; 
    select(length==2));


all(pairs(inputs); sorted)
```

Invocation:

```
jq -n -f sorted.jq input.json
```

---

If the stars are aligned properly and you want a one-liner:

```
jq 'all(foreach [inputs[]] as $i ([[.[]]]; [.[-1],$i]); .[0]<=.[1])' input.json
```

Season to taste.